# Make the "Ruler/Protractor" measurements to appear on renders

Tags: rendering, measurement

I recently realized that blender have a "Ruler/Protractor" tool for precise measurements. Is there a way to make those measurements appear on final renders?
(By the way, is there a way to customize the transparency of those measurement value displays?)

Thanks in advance for replies.

(I am using cycle for render, but it is fine if I have to use Blender Internal for the measurements to appear)

Comment: I don't think this is possible. The only way I can think of is by taking a screenshot and compositing it on somehow.. You might just be better off modeling your own ruler/protractor using the snapping tools (you would have to add the numbers manually).

Comment: Well, taking screenshot have the limit of resolution. Maybe the solution is really manually modelling the measurements. Is it possible that there is some sort of python addin that can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A small trick is to temporarily increase the **DPI** value (located in **User Preferences** > **System** (maximum to 144), then maximize the 3D window and capture the screen. (Maximize the desktop resolution before that if possible).

[image]

However, you are right about the limit of resolution, so this is the last choice, I guess, unless capturing several parts and tiling them manually.

Comment: Thanks. This solve the problem of the small text at least. And I think this is the solution for now

Comment: Would an OpenGL render be better than a screenshot?

Comment: @AnsonSavage, AFAIK it isn't supported. Anway you may want to try some addons such as MeasureIt.